# Connecting to gtalk in irssi errors with 301

Tags: xmpp, google-talk, irssi

I have irssi and the xmpp plugin configured:

```
    {                                                                             
    address = "talk.google.com";                                                
    chatnet = "Gtalk";                                                          

    autoconnect = "yes";                                                        
    port = "5223";                                                              
    #use_ssl = "yes";                                                           
    #ssl_verify = "yes";                                                        
    ssl_capath = "/etc/ssl/certs";                                              
  }
```

and

```
Gtalk = { type = "XMPP"; nick = "neilhwatson@gmail.com"; };
```

This error is returned:

```
09:09 [Gtalk] -!- HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
09:09 [Gtalk] -!- Location: http://www.google.com/hangouts/
09:09 [Gtalk] -!- Content-Type: text/html
09:09 [Gtalk] -!- Content-Length: 178
```

Is there some other host or port combination that will work?

Comment: Is that going to resist for long, given Google is gradually requiring OAuth 2.0 for authentication? (http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html)
Cf. https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/hangouts/aHdaUoK7oTI/qZR6UwApmJcJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DNS SRV](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records):

```
$ dig SRV _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com. 337 IN     SRV     20 0 5222 alt2.xmpp.l.google.com.
_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com. 337 IN     SRV     20 0 5222 alt3.xmpp.l.google.com.
_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com. 337 IN     SRV     5 0 5222 xmpp.l.google.com.
_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com. 337 IN     SRV     20 0 5222 alt1.xmpp.l.google.com.
_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com. 337 IN     SRV     20 0 5222 alt4.xmpp.l.google.com.
```

You could try using `xmpp.l.google.com`. My XMPP client (pidgin) seems to do this automatically when I tell it that the domain is "gmail.com"

Comment: Good answer, FYI, now I see this error, but that is Irssi specific. warning None of the Subject Alt Names in the certificate match hostname 'xmpp.l.google.com'